# How can I edit an iframe with proxy?

Tags: php, iframe, proxy

I need to edit an iframe with jQuery but I'm unable to do it.

I tried with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iframe").on('load',function(){
        $(this).contents().find('body').html('a');
    });
});
```

This code doesn't work.

**EDIT**

The iframe is related to a different domain.

Comment: Same origin policy?  Is this iframe on your domain?

Comment: No. This iframe is other domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just answered your own question. Your code doesn't work because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can use a PHP proxy to bypass this restriction.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://example.com";
    $domain = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $domain;
?>
```

And then use that information in your script.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952) question has more details about this issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But doesn't it break the layout when the target page has non-absolute URLs and relative links?